# New Sonar IntelliJ plugin incremental analysis and detection not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, code-analysis

I’d like to ask for help. I installed the [plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+IntelliJ) and successfully added the SonarQube server. I upgraded to version 4.1.2. I use IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2.
I also successfully associated the project and inspection warnings appeared. But when I fix the issue the status is not updated.

1. How to synchronize ?

I also run inspection by name ‘SonarQube issues’. 
Nevertheless after running the inspection the warnings are also there, where the code was fixed. It seems to me the synchronization somehow fails.
Any idea, what todo, please?

Comment: I have the same problem, it looks like instead working in 'incremental' mode, the plugin just displays the issues fetched from soanrqube server, local code is never analysed.

Comment: Me too i have the same problem. Moreover, it seems that the number of issues to be listed by IntelliJ is limited to 10 000. I have more issues on sonar server.

Comment: Limit of 10000 issue is a server side limitation (same as when doing a search). It will be fixed in 5.0 by using Elastic Search internally.

Answer (score 2):

What I had done in my situation.

- Installed SonarQube 4.4.
- Installed IntelliJ 13.1.4b (the same history was with 13.0.4).
- Configured SonarQube intelliJ plugin (not community provided one but [plugin from SonarSource](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+IntelliJ;jsessionid=59A6EA6412C0F510C3415B687322BF81)). All instructions are under the link on Wiki.
- Attached to Sonar project. Every step just as SonarSource recommends.

  This gave me mapping from Sonar onto source code. But it does not update when I simply fix the issue. But if I fix issues I then re-post project onto Sonar through `mvn sonar:sonar` and this gives me updated picture next time I run inspection through sonarqube plugin.

But this is not 100% what is wanted. But definitely better than nothing. Also I have imported Sonar rules through `QAPlug` - this is far less useful. But notable faster.

Overall this configuration allows me to make what is needed but I'd like to receive real incremental processing without publishing local changes onto Sonar server.

Comment: Roman, thanks for taking time to poste this but it doesn't answer jguru's question.

Comment: @Hui This situation is exactly what I have and the only solution (actually workaround) I have found is this, HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the SonarQube IntelliJ Community Plugin, it is made for fixing issues detected by jenkins on the local dev machine. Different then the official plugin you will need to do more configuration by yourself, but it gives you also the freedom to specify your local analysis script like you need.

What you need to do:

- configure the plugin

  - setup sonar server
  - setup local analysis script

Afterwards you can run SonarQube (new issues) inspection, this will run the script and show the results in the Intellij. If you are fixing issues, you can just rerun the inspection from inside the inspections results tool window. This will rerun the script and show new results.

see also: https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin